# How to use a "sql compact " database from non .NET language?

Tags: vb6, sql-server-ce

How to use sql compact database from a non .NET program?
For example I want to access from VB6

I want to use a database populated by C# in sql compact.
I don't access c# program source to change it's database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compact edition has an OLEDB driver so it should work with ADO.

something like this in VB6:

```
Set connection = New ADODB.Connection
connection.Provider = "Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5"
connection.Open "C:\FileName.sdf"
```